# Is <img :src="require`${JSON.parse(string)}`"> in electron vue is safe from XSS?

Tags: xss, javascript

I am inspecting a client's application written with Vue.js and I found there a following construction.

```
// Somewhere else in the code
var data = JSON.parse(jsonString); 

// In the vue component
<img :src="require(`@/assets/img/${data.someKey}.png`)">
```

jsonString is returned from a client's own server, however if the server is compromised then this data can be manipulated.

The application is running in electron environment.

Is this construction is safe to assume that data.someKey will always contain a safe data or there are some ways to abuse this construction and execute an XSS either though a require or through ${}?

The whole construction is very questionable and client's developers are convinced that JSON.parse is a sufficient protection in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Vue templates and React/JSX don't describe HTML source code, they describe a HTML DOM, an object model. This completely avoids typical XSS attacks. In particular, the template is completely parsed before data-binding is evaluated, so contents of variables cannot change how the template is parsed. Even if the `data.someKey` were to contain content such as `"> <script>alert("pwned")</script>`, this is just data and will not be parsed as HTML, unless very specific workarounds such as [Vue's `v-html` directive](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-html) are used.

Translated to more normal JavaScript, the shown Vue snippet would correspond roughly to:

```
const img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = require("@/assets/img/" + data.someKey + ".png");
someContext.appendChild(img);
```

Because of this, I think that the focus on `JSON.parse()` is a red herring here. It doesn't really matter what the data format is, it only matters how the data is used.

If there is a chance for some problem here, it is going to be the `require()` function. Normally, requires/imports are resolved at build-time, but here the resource to be loaded is specified at runtime. Depending on the exact syntax of this `require()` implementation, there might be issues such as path traversals or type confusions. While PNG files would typically be loaded as a base64-encoded data-URI, a require function would more often be used to load (and execute) other code modules.